# Remote Validation Hitting Function Twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, remote-validation

I'm facing 2 issues while learning remote validation. First is that the values of int are being passed individually (e.g 123 being passed like 1 and 2 being sent in the next call). The second issue I'm facing is that each call is running twice in the controller. Here is the code of my model.

```
    //Model
   [Remote("CheckPhoneNum", "Employee", ErrorMessage = "Phone Number Must Start With 03 And Should Contain 11 Digits")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Mobile No")]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Number")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public int Mobile { get; set; }
```

View Code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mobile, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my controller:

```
public JsonResult CheckPhoneNum(int Mobile)
    {
        string number = Convert.ToString(Mobile);
        if (number.Substring(0,1).Equals("0") && number.Substring(1,2).Equals("3") && number.Length==11)
            return Json(true,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post your code not an image of it

Comment: Updated. Please take a look again.